# Create two versions of my software in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am setting up Gitlab CI for the first time, and I want it to create two releases for each commit. My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
stages:
  - compile
  - test
  - build release

compile apps:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - scons
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - deliverables/

check version:
  stage: test
  script:
    - check_version.sh

build releasefile:
  stage: build release
  script:
    - build_release.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release/
```

For my second version, I want to run scons in compile apps with a flag (`scons --special`) and then run all next jobs as well on those deliverables. My deliverables are named the same for both versions, and if I just create jobs for both the normal and special version, my "check version" job will check the normal version twice. My options:

- Create a really long pipeline that runs everything of the normal version and then everything of the special version. I don't like this solution, it looks hideous and can make errors less visible when the pipeline is expanded later.
- Change my scons and shell scripts.
- Create two pipelines on each commit, one with a Gitlab CI flag and one without (I don't know how to do this).
- Create a "split" pipeline that only uses stuff from the job that it is based on (I don't know how to do this).

For the last case, my pipeline would look something like this:

```
-----+------ Compile normal ----- Check version ----- Build releasefile
     |
     +----- Compile special ----- Check version ----- Build releasefile
```

I would prefer option 3 or 4 and I've been looking at Directed Acyclic Graph Pipelines, but I can't get those to work in the way I want. Is there a way to do either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a DAG pipeline with [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#needs). If you don't use `needs` (or the older `dependencies`), all artifacts from previous stages will be downloaded, which in this case is problematic due to the overlap in the artifact folders / names.

You can also use [`extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#extends) to avoid duplication in your job declarations. The full `.gitlab-ci.yml` config could be something like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - compile
  - test
  - build release

compile apps:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - scons
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - deliverables/

compile apps special:
  extends:
    - compile apps
  script:
    - scons --special

check version:
  stage: test
  script:
    - check_version.sh
  needs:
    - compile apps

check version special:
  extends:
    - check version
  needs:
    - compile apps special

build releasefile:
  stage: build release
  script:
    - build_release.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release/
  needs:
    - compile apps
    - check version

build releasefile special:
  extends:
    - build releasefile
  needs:
    - compile apps special
    - check version special
```

`extends` works well in this context because it doesn't combine YAML list items, but instead overwrites them (keys with different names would get merged, on the other hand). So in this case, the whole `script` and `needs` declarations get overwritten by the inheriting job.

Comment: Thanks for the script, and for the extra suggestion on `extends`! The strange thing is that it appears to work but the graphical representation of the pipeline is wrong - normal "compile" is linked to both "check version" and "check version special", and "compile special" is linked to normal "check version" only. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: That sounds like a visual problem of the "Pipeline"-View. DAG pipelines (using `needs`) are a newer feature, which can be visualized in the "Needs"-Tab when viewing a pipeline. That one should show you two parallel pipes.

You could also add `when: manual` to all jobs for testing so you can check if all dependencies work properly. When combined with `needs`, you won't be able to start a job before its dependencies finish.

Comment: Ah yes, the "needs" tab displays it like I expected, thanks for the help!